# when i click a marker in map i cant show the place detail how can?

Tags: android, android-layout

when i click the marker no response

this is the code

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event, MapView mv) 
{   
    if (event.getAction() == 1) 
    {                
        GeoPoint g = mv.getProjection().fromPixels((int) event.getX(),(int) event.getY());
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), g.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6 + "," + g.getLongitudeE6() /1E6 , 
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
        return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Calling on touch through dispatch touch event. It worked for me.

I am not sure why but onTouch works only the first time. Calling it through dispatch touch event calls it every time.

Is there anything you wanna know?